# Qml QtQuick2 'Invalid property name "style"(M16)'

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2

I'm writing a mobile application in Qt5.7.0 QtCreator 4.1 and i'm getting the error in QtQuick qml file 'Invalid property name "style"(M16)' and form does not want to display something. What i'm doing wrong?

Must i configure something in the project before or use another type of file?

I tried to use this property on some components and it works only with Text object and i don't know why.

Here's my code:

```
//register_form.qml
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
Item {
    width: 270
    height: 480
    anchors.fill: parent

    ColumnLayout {
        id: loginLayout
        anchors.rightMargin: 15
        anchors.bottomMargin: 92
        anchors.leftMargin: 23
        anchors.topMargin: 91
        anchors.fill: parent

        TextField {
            TextFieldStyle {
                    id: phoneStyle
                    placeholderTextColor: "grey"
            }
            id: phoneField
            placeholderText: "+7 XXX XXX XX XX"
            Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignBottom
        }

        Button {
             style: //error occurs here
                 ButtonStyle {
                 } 
        id: loginButton
        text: "Next"
        Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignHCenter | Qt.AlignTop
        highlighted: true
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Button` from Controls 2 [doesn't have](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls2-button-members.html) a `style` property. The `Button` that has it was [the one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-button.html#style-prop) from Controls 1.

As for styling Controls 2 elements, [take a look here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-styles.html).

Comment: More relevant part of documentation is here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html#porting-qt-quick-controls-1-code